# Monthly interval between two date

Tags: c#, date

I have two dates like 2017-10-05 and 2018-02-20, my interval result should be:

```
2017-10-05
2017-10-31
2017-11-30
2017-12-31
2018-01-31
2018-02-20
2018-02-28
```

Any suggestions to do this in C# using DateTime object?

**UPDATE #1**

The problem I mentioned first concerns is a real situation of a cash flow management, so I had to change dates specifications for the calculation of interest, dif and civ. This code i use for the purpose:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in DTFlussi.Rows)
{
    DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(DTFlussi.Rows[n]["data_scadenza"]).Date;
    DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(DTFlussi.Rows[n + 1]["data_scadenza"]).Date;
    int[] date = RecuperoDate(d1, d2);

    if (saldoConto > 0)
        InteressiAttivi(saldoConto, date, DTOneri, d1, d2);
    else if (saldoConto <= 0 && saldoConto >= (fidoConto * -1))
    {
        //esempio di interessi FIDO al 2%
        InteressiFido(saldoConto, date, tassoFIDO, DTOneri, d1, d2);
    }
    else if (saldoConto < 0 && saldoConto < (fidoConto * -1))
    {
        //esempio con interessi FIDO al 2% e interessi EXTRAFIDO al 4%
        InteressiExtraFido(saldoConto, fidoConto, date, tassoFIDO, tassoEXTRAFIDO, DTOneri, d1, d2);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
    n++;
}
```

The code for RecuperoDate is:

```
public int[] RecuperoDate(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
    int[] diff = new int[2];

    //Gestione anno bisestile Febbrario
    int giorniFebbraio = 0;
    if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(d1.Year))
        giorniFebbraio = 29;
    else
        giorniFebbraio = 28;

    try
    {
        #region MESE 1

        if (d1.Date >= new DateTime(d1.Year, 1, 1) && d1.Date <= new DateTime(d1.Year, 1, 31) && d2.Date >= new DateTime(d1.Year, 1, 31))
        {
            DateTime Mese1 = new DateTime(d1.Year, 1, 31).Date;
            diff[0] = (int)(Mese1 - d1).TotalDays;
            diff[1] = (int)(d2 - Mese1).TotalDays;
        }

        #endregion

        //NOTE: incomplete code because is the same thing for the other months (February - December)
```

This is necessary to obtain subsequent variations in the balance and at the end of the calculations this is what I want: 
[image]

Comment: What is the pattern of your resultset? Looks a bit confused

Comment: What have you tried? DateTime1 + x amount of days until DateTime1 is bigger than DateTime2?

Comment: What do you mean `monthly interval` and how are those values generated? You have multiple dates in the same month

Comment: @RvdK that would guarantee an error, especially in February and leap years. The correct way is to use `AddMonth`

Comment: yes, I have to get a monthly report from these dates like the seven lines that i wrote, also i have to get it the number of days between two dates, like 26, 30, 31, 31, 20, 8 but this is immediate if i have the end months

Comment: So the pattern is `the last day of each month in the range including the two dates given`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Correct, I was confused what the interval should be. I assumed days between, if it's month's than you should use AddMonth to cater for Leap years and other weird DateTime changes countries do.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array.

```
            DateTime[] dateArray = {
                                       DateTime.Parse("2017-10-05"),
                                       DateTime.Parse("2017-10-31"),
                                       DateTime.Parse("2017-11-30"),
                                       DateTime.Parse("2017-12-31"),
                                       DateTime.Parse("2018-02-20"),
                                       DateTime.Parse("2018-02-28")
                                   };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the latest day in each month. The `DateTime` struct provides a static `DaysInMonth`method, that takes the year and the month as parameters.

Going from there, you could iterate from the start date to the end date and get the dates.

This code will print the desired dates to the console, although the format isn't exaclty what you requested:

```
    DateTime start = new DateTime(2017,10,05);
    DateTime end = new DateTime(2018,2,20);
    DateTime current = start;

    Console.WriteLine(start.ToShortDateString());
    int startLastDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth(start.Year, start.Month);
    if(startLastDay != start.Day)
        Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month, startLastDay).ToShortDateString());


    while(current < end)
    {
        current = current.AddMonths(1);
        if(current > end)
            Console.WriteLine(end.ToShortDateString());

        int lastDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth(current.Year, current.Month);
        current = new DateTime(current.Year, current.Month, lastDay);
        Console.WriteLine(current.ToShortDateString());
    }
```

edit:

Here the console output on my machine:

```
10/5/2017
10/31/2017
11/30/2017
12/31/2017
1/31/2018
2/20/2018
2/28/2018
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<string> GetIntervals(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    result.Add(startDate.ToShortDateString());
    result.Add(endDate.ToShortDateString());
    DateTime target = startDate;
    while (target <= endDate) {
        result.Add(new DateTime(target.Year, target.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(target.Year, target.Month)).ToShortDateString());
        target = target.AddMonths(1);
    }
    result = result.Distinct().ToList();
    result.Sort();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2017, 10, 5);
        var endDate = new DateTime(2018, 2, 20);

        var firstDayofMonth = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(1);

        Console.WriteLine(startDate.ToShortDateString());

        while (true)
        {
            var dateToCompare = firstDayofMonth.AddDays(-1);

            //Last month
            if (dateToCompare >= endDate)
            {
                if (dateToCompare > endDate)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(endDate.ToShortDateString());
                }
                Console.WriteLine(dateToCompare.ToShortDateString());
                break;
            }

            if (dateToCompare != startDate)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dateToCompare.ToShortDateString());
            }

            firstDayofMonth = firstDayofMonth.AddMonths(1);
        }
```